# How is ordering guaranteed during failures in Kafka Async Producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

If I am using Kafka Async producer, assume there are X number of messages in buffer. 
When they are actually processed on the client, and if broker or a specific partition is down for sometime, kafka client would retry and if a message is failed, would it mark the specific message as failed and move on to the next message (this could lead to out of order messages) ? Or, would it fail the remaining messages in the batch in order to preserve order?

I next to maintain the ordering, so would ideally want to kafka to fail the batch from the place where it failed, so I can retry from the failure point, how would I achieve that?

Comment: Kafka will only retry if you have changed the default setting of retires. fron kafka docs: Allowing retries will potentially change the ordering of records because if two records are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the second record may appear first.

Answer (score 1):

Like it says in the kafka documentation about retries

> Setting a value greater than zero will cause the client to resend any
>   record whose send fails with a potentially transient error. Note that
>   this retry is no different than if the client resent the record upon
>   receiving the error. Allowing retries will potentially change the
>   ordering of records because if two records are sent to a single
>   partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds,
>   then the second record may appear first.

So, answering to your title question, no kafka doesn't have order guarantees under async sends.

---

I am updating the answers base on Peter Davis question.

I think that if you want to send in batch mode, the only way to secure it I would be to set the  `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1` but as the documentation says:

> Note that if this setting is set to be greater than 1 and there are
>   failed sends, there is a risk of message re-ordering due to retries
>   (i.e., if retries are enabled).

Comment: This doesn't answer the behavior if retries=0.  If you do require ordering, but want to send in batch without calling Future.get() after each send, can I set retries=0 and expect that if the producer fails to send one message, then it will fail all subsequent messages to the partition to preserve ordering?

Comment: You can rely on Kafka ordering as long as you set retries to zero and each of your topics has only one partition. You do not have to set max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1 as you only have a single partition so Kafka will only ever have 1 in flight request as partitions are kafka mechanism for parallism

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Kafka 0.11.0, there is the `enable.idempotence` setting, as [documented](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).

> **enable.idempotence**: When set to `true`, the producer will ensure that
>   exactly one copy of each message is written in the stream. If `false`,
>   producer retries due to broker failures, etc., may write duplicates of
>   the retried message in the stream. Note that enabling idempotence
>   requires `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to be less than or
>   equal to `5`, retries to be greater than 0 and `acks` must be `all`. If
>   these values are not explicitly set by the user, suitable values will
>   be chosen. If incompatible values are set, a `ConfigException` will be
>   thrown.
>
> ```
> Type: boolean Default: false
> ```

This will guarantee that **messages are ordered and that no loss occurs for the duration of the producer session**. Unfortunately, the producer cannot set the sequence id, so Kafka can make these guarantees only per producer session.

Have a look at Apache Pulsar if you need to [set the sequence id](https://pulsar.apache.org/api/client/org/apache/pulsar/client/api/TypedMessageBuilder.html#sequenceId-long-), which would allow you to use an external sequence id, which would guarantee ordered and exactly-once messaging across both broker and producer failovers.